# Ajax error when uploading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I try to upload an image to a server using technology Ajax.
Console output error:

```
POST http://localhost:4246/pr_with_div/pr_per.aspx 500(Interval server Error)
send
jQuery.extend.ajax
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemdata.handle
```

Can you please tell how to fix it?

1) page pos.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="pos.aspx.cs" Inherits="pos" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mainForm").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = new FormData($('#mainForm')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "pr_per.aspx",
                data: data,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loader').show();
                }
            })
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="mainForm" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload"   Text="Upload"  /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2) page pr_per.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="pr_per.aspx.cs" Inherits="pr_per" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%

    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];


    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/img/", fname)));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried playing a `try...catch` around your `file.SaveAs`? Can you set breakpoints to see if the first line gets executed? A `500` error indicates a problem with the server-side, so that is what you need to debug.

Comment: 500 errors usually come with a log message on the server side. You should check it out, it might help you understand what the problem is. Although with IIS it might be more difficult to find the logs.

Comment: @JamesHay,yes i do  try
        {
            string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/img/", fname)));
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        { 
        
        }

Comment: But i think that problem in ajax jquery

Comment: Why do you think that? Have you added an `error` and `success` function to the AJAX request and logged the result? Is the server being hit at all? In order to solve the problem you first will need to find the problem.